# Table relationships Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I already have,let's say,a table named "Domain" and a table named "Nodes" and i want to make a dependecy on my webinterface where --Domain have Nodes-- and --Nodes can't exist without my Domain--!In general i want my Nodes be inside my domain graphically.In which way is that possible?

--Edited--

Well in my Nodes table i have this one "domains = models.ForeignKey(Domains)" so now as i can understand i can see the dependency i want.Now,on the web-interface i have i want to press the "Domain" table and then when i am inside to see the "Nodes" table.I want to see on my interface the dependecy tat "Domain have Nodes"

Thanks in regards!

Comment: *"i want my Nodes be inside my domain graphically"* What do you mean by graphically in this? But yeah, what's wrong with the very basic Django [ForeignKey relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)?

Comment: Well in my Nodes table i have this one
"domains = models.ForeignKey(Domains)" so now i can see the dependecy i want?Or?
By "graphically" i mean that i want to press "Domains" on my interface and then inside to be able to see the "Nodes" table!

Comment: *"so now i can the dependecy in want"* ?? I don't get this part. *"i want to press "Domains" on my interface and"* What interface? We rely on information you provide in your question, we can't guess what you mean. And please **edit** your question to provide more information. Comments are not fit for that and this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: Are you talking about the contrib.admin Admin interface by chance?

Comment: yes i am talking about this one

Comment: What have you tried? This is in the Django tutorial. Include at least the code you're now using to register the models in the Admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

start a project Konto ( start terminal )

```
django-admin.py startproject konto
cd konto/

python manage.py startapp test
```

open your setting.py inside ( konto/ )

add `'test',` & uncomment `'django.contrib.admin',` in INSTALLED_APPS tuple

Edit and add to DATABASES

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
'NAME': 'test.sqlite3',
```

Edit test/models.py

```
class Domain(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     url = models.URLField()

     def __unicode__(self):
          return self.name

class Node(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain)

     def __unicode__(self):
          return self.name
```

add a admin.py file to your app (test):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Domain,Node

admin.site.register(Domain)
admin.site.register(Node)
```

Edit konto/urls.py

uncomment below

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
....................
.................... 
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Syncdb ( Terminal ) & create your super user

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

mention **username: admin**  and **password : admin123** while ask when you run above command

Run Server

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Eg :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
```

login with **username: admin**  and **password : admin123**

Add Node

Cheers !!

Comment: You're not registering any of the models in the admin interface. Even with `admin.autodiscover()`, your models won't be listed. Again, see the Django tutorial on [*Make the poll app modifiable in the admin*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial02/#make-the-poll-app-modifiable-in-the-admin)

Comment: Here i forget to add admin.py adding that now.. Thanks to remind me